# How do I fade out the contents of a scrollview in Xamarin Forms iOS? Fade out top and bottom when there is an additional content

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

There is a [half solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67805690/how-do-i-fade-out-the-contents-of-a-scrollview-in-xamarin-forms-ios) here. But this only fades out the bottom layer not the top layer when there is an additional content. I want to fade out both top and bottom layer when there is an additional content.

This custom renderer implements it perfectly for android. Unfortunately iOS does not provide an api like VerticalFadingEdgeEnabled

```
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FadeScrollView), typeof(FadeScrollViewRendererAndroid))]
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class FadeScrollViewRendererAndroid : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        public FadeScrollViewRendererAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            this.SetFadingEdgeLength(300);
            this.VerticalFadingEdgeEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

sample image

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fade out the contents of a scrollview in Xamarin Forms iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67805690/how-do-i-fade-out-the-contents-of-a-scrollview-in-xamarin-forms-ios)

Comment: This is the link I added in my post. It only fades the bottom layer. But I want the top layer to fade as well if there is an additional content at the top.

Comment: One possible way that comes to my mind is to put custom gradient overlays in scrollview, as some discussions on swift UI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75502208/fade-in-out-scrollview-swift-ui